# My Basic kernel with bootloader doesn't work when the final image file bigger then 2^14 size

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel

My Basic kernel with bootloader doesn't work when the final image file bigger then 2^14 size. Atleast I think this is the problem.

My github repo: https://github.com/domonkosgyomorey/simple_os_template
The repo contains the error (I will fix it).

When I started to implement basic memory management with the Buddy algorithm I had this problem.
When I am deleted a functions in the memory.c file (the buddy_free) and recompile the whole project it works fine.

The next step. I tried to add some bytes with a char array to fill up the 2^14 space and when I step over the 16384 size it doesn't work after. So I think that is my problem, but I can't figure it out what could be the cousing this problem.

(And I also tried to debug with the bochs debugger, but It was a mess :( )

I hope someone can help me to figure it out the problem ( I am just learning this topic )

Comment: `boot_main` seems to load 31 sectors from disk. How much data is that?

Comment: @BoP
oh, thank you!
Is this bad design? or what is the average sector number i should read?

Comment: Obviously you should know the size of your kernel and read that many sectors. Have the build system fill it in,or put some header into the first sector so you know how many more to read.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires relevant part of the **code** to be in the **question post** itself. A link to an external site doesn't fulfil that requirement. See [ask].